# Disable horizontal scrolling in WebPart

Tags: web-part, css

From codebehind I add to my webpart controls

```
_grid=new SPGridView()
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                            div.Attributes.Add("id", "div-datagrid");
                            div.Attributes.Add("style", "overflow: auto;");
                            div.Controls.Add(_grid);
                            Controls.Add(div);
```

The problem is that entire page is scrolling instead only my grid.

Result is as on the picture:

[image]

How to enable scrolling only for that grid?

Answer (score 1):

You must set width in order to use overflow:auto. Try to set width:100%.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need horizontal scroll set then I would use `overflow-x: auto` or `overflow-x: scroll`.

Difference is that browser can automatically decide if scroll is needed OR it will always show one (even if not necessarily needed). I have found that this is not always consistent behaviour. Sometimes browser will decide to scretch page rather than show scroll if you don't specify width on your grid (div that contains your grid).

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp